# Apache license in non-Apache licensed software; how to distinguish?

Tags: licensing, apache-license

The Apache License states:

"You must give any other recipients of the Work or Derivative Works a copy of this License;"

So if you've copied a bunch of functions from some Apache-licensed code (so it's not just linking, you've borrowed code) into a product *that is not itself Apache-licensed*, what's a good way to indicate that the license you included only applies to some bits of code in your product, not to the product as a whole?  (To avoid the suggestion that the product as a whole is freely copyable.)

Should a list of projects you've borrowed from and their various licenses be included in the "About" screen for the product, *insisting* that the licenses only apply to those bits?  I'm asking because that seems to make sense, but I don't recall seeing that anywhere.

Answer (score 2):

From a coding perspective, try your best to segregate and encapsulate the Apache parts.

From a license perspective, I would just note in the About screen "Some aspects of the $myproduct codebase covered under the Apache license" or something like that. You don't need to specify which pieces, unless there's a specific, named algorithm that you're borrowing,